# Switch to data selection meaning?

Tags: rules, theming

I'm setting up rules, trying to setup HTML emailing. I've it setup but not sure how to configure it. What does *Switch to data selection* mean?'

Comment: Please ask one thing at a time. And whole manual for configuration of SMTP is simply too broad for Q&A format.

Comment: Help with either would be helpful :) I'm hoping that an answer to my first question will help me understand the second. It's already configured, I just don't see where the option is to send html emails is

Answer (score 0):

For an email action, there are 2 different input modes for the fields in *Send HTML email* action.

1. **Direct input mode:** You're supplying most of the data (e.g. the HTML body) with different token (e.g. `[site:slogan]`) inserted in it.
2. **Data selector mode:** You're using a widget (see image) that lets you drill into data that the Rules action has available. This is useful for finding contextual data (e.g. retrieving the current user's email when a node is updated).

[image: Data selector widget]